# E-mail scanner help -> compare words in mail to dictonary

Tags: python, email, dictionary, io

I'm trying to write a simple program in which you paste the text of a certain email, and the program print a which dic has the most overlap with the email.

Here a quick overview of what I'm trying to achieve:

1. User copies and pastes email into program
2. Text gets stored to variable
3. Variable gets appended to text file (to build a simple database of all emails)
4. Each word in variable gets compared to words in 4 different categories(dics)
5. Every time a word from the email matches with a word in a dic, some separate variables keep track of this.
6. In the end the programs shows the prediction. So all 4 categories with the number of times words of that dic where in the email.

So far my program saves the input to a single, lowercase string and appends that to a text file.

So how can I iterate over each word in the newest entry to the text file and check which of the 4 dics has the most similar words.

This is what I have so far.

```
content = ""
line = input(">")

while line != "EOF":
    line = line.lower()
    content += line
    line = input(">")

file = open('Email_file.txt','a')
file.write('-- START --' + '\n' + content + "\n" + '-- FINISH --')

list_1={
    'word1':1,
    'word2':1,
    'word4':1}

list_2={
    'word5':1,
    'word6':1,
    'word7':1}

list_3={
    'word8':1,
    'word9':1,
    'word10':1}

list_4={
    'word11':1,
    'word12':1,
    'word13':1}
```

To give a little background on how I want to use this: 
I get a lot of emails that usually are classifiable into 1 of 4 types. Instead of manually categorizing each mail, I want to write a program that predict's the likeliness of each category based on words in the email. I want to add a small machine learning part into it later by asking the user if the prediction was right, and if so increasing the number behind the word in the dics, so I can later translate this into how heavy each word weighs. But that's all for later. For now I just want it to compare the content of the email to 4 lists and print which list has the highest number of corresponding words.

---- UPDATE --- 
When I try to run your code:
    from collections import Counter

```
a = Counter({
    'hello':1,
    'bye':1,
    'see you':1,})

b = Counter({
    'tomorrow':1,
    'today':1,
    'last week':1,})

c = Counter({
    'walk':1,
    'bike':1,
    'swim':1,
    'run':1,})

with open("emailfile.txt") as f:
    # for every line
    for line in f:
        # split line into words
        spl = line.split()
        # update count for each word set
        # a.keys() & spl finds any common words
        a.update(a.keys() & spl) # .viewkeys() for python2
        b.update(b.keys() & spl)
        c.update(c.keys() & spl)

# find word set with most occurrences
print(max((a, b, c), key=lambda x: sum(x.values())))
```

and emailfile.txt contains:

- hello, last week i bought my bike and today i am using it bike. then
  i walk.

it prints:
    Counter({'bike': 2, 'walk': 1, 'swim': 1, 'run': 1})

I don't see what it does since it keeps 'walk' on 1 even though it is in the file.

I want it to print something like: 
    Highest nr. of corresponding: C with 3 similar words

Thanks!!

Comment: Loop over the words, increment a count for each wordset and return the max

Comment: How do i loop over words in a text file? For i in text.txt doesn't work in this case i believe

Comment: I added an example of how to approach the problem, there are other factors  but it should give you a general idea

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough idea of how to count the words and find the most frequently occurring in the file using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dicts:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

# Counter dicts will count the occurrences for each word set
a = Counter({
    'word1': 0,
    'word2': 0,
    'word4': 0})

b = Counter({
    'word5': 0,
    'word6': 0,
    'word7': 0})

c = Counter({
    'word8': 0,
    'word9': 0,
    'word10': 0})

d = Counter({
    'word11': 0,
    'word12': 0,
    'word13': 0})

with open("emailfile.txt") as f:
    # for every line
    for line in f:
        # split line into words, remove punctuation and lower
        spl = [w.strip(punctuation).lower() for w in line.split()]
        # update count for each word set
        # a.keys() & spl finds any common words
        a.update(a.keys() & spl) # .viewkeys() for python2
        b.update(b.keys() & spl)
        c.update(c.keys() & spl)
        d.update(d.keys() & spl)

# find word set with most occurrences
print(max((a, b, c, d), key=lambda x: sum(x.values())))
```

Or store the words in separate lists and use a single Counter dict:

```
a = [..]
b = [...]
 # etc...
from itertools import chain
with open("emailfile.txt") as f:
    cn = Counter(chain(*(w.strip(punctuation).lower() for w in line.split()) for line in f))


print(max((a, b, c, d), key=lambda x: sum(cn[w] for w in x)))
```

Comment: Hi Padraic, thanks for your help so far! I have a hard time figuring out what you code does.

Comment: @NieldeVries, it gets all the words from the file, does a count of each for each set of words then returns the max based on the word set that had the most occurrences.

Comment: I tried to clarify it more with an update in my original question. I don't understand how it counts.

Comment: That is what  a `Counter` dict does,  ah, ok, you need to strip the punctuation, I will edit. Is your file ascii only?

Comment: Yes it's ascii only. Thanks for helping out. I'm trying to grasp the logic behind it!

Comment: @NieldeVries, all we are doing is using dictionaries to count the words, each dict is a word set, then `sum(cn[w] for w in x)` as the key to max will give you the dict with the highest

Comment: I understand the counting now, it counts every word uniquely not each time it appears in the email, which is good. I implemented it into my code but I'm still having issues. 

Every time a word from a email occurs in one of the word sets, the value of that key(the word) is +1. That sounds good. But the next time I enter an email, the program looks for the word set with the highest count and doesn't look at how many time the word appears in the email.  So for example if word2 appears in the first 4 email entries, the value of word2 = 5 so the program will conclude that that is the right wordset

Comment: It counts it every time it appears, if you don't want to count the same words more than once then first make a `set` from the words. I presume we are talking small amounts of data? Also what happens if you do only count occurrences once and you have a three or two way tie?

Comment: The main function is to categorize each email that I enter, into the category that has the most occurring words with the email.

Besides that, I want to build a small 'database' that keeps track of how many times the words in the word sets appear in the emails I enter. That is why I want to use the dic.

Since this program will be used to 'categorize' a tie should print the 2 or 3 categories that tie. 

I'd like to build a small machine learning part in this, but it's too early for me.

Comment: If `foo` is a word and  `"foo bar foo"` the count for foo should be 1 or 2?

Comment: Should be 1. But storing it in a dic creates a problem. 
A short example would clarify it better. 

Wordset1{foo:1, world:1}
Wordset2{green:1, apple:1}

email 1: foo
prediction: wordset1

Wordset1{foo:2, world:1}
Wordset2{green:1, apple:1}


email2: green
prediciton: wordset1 (because the count for foo just went up, and is lower then count for green)

Wordset1{foo:2, world:1}
Wordset2{green:2, apple:1}

Damn the formatting in this comments suck

Comment: Then use a set, sets cannot have dupes so just find the intersection of the sets https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects